# My specific installation of Safari refuses to open my website

Tags: macos, caching, https, safari, dns

My copy of Safari refuses to open my website, `example.com`.

Every time I try and visit `http://example.com` Safari (not the server!) redirects me to `https://example.com`, and immediately tells me:

> "Safari can't open the page "https://example.com" because Safari can't connect to the server "example.com".

- The site does not have HTTPS enabled or a certificate installed (though it once did)
- The site works perfectly in Chrome
- The site works perfectly in iOS Safari
- The site works perfectly in Safari on a different computer

It seems like my copy of Safari has 'cached' the HTTPS redirect or something.

Here is what I have tried:

- Clearing the Safari cache
- Disabling the Safari cache
- Clearing the OS X DNS cache
- System reboots
- Intentionally accessing the HTTPS version
- Intentionally accessing the HTTP version
- Appending random query strings

But still every time I instantly get the message. It appears in a matter of milliseconds making me assume it's cached somewhere.

When trying on a Guest account, the problem goes away. However, both my Mac at home and at work are affected, presumably because iCloud is syncing some kind of Safari cache file.

[This thread here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5884595?start=0&tstart=0) seems to hint it is to do with HSTS (as @rluta has thought), or alternatively to do with `Strict-Transport-Security` headers being set. I have confirmed and no `Strict-Transport-Security` headers are being set when the webpage is accessed.

If at all possible I really don't want to have to "reset" my copy of Safari as I use it for everything day to day. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Mac OS X user account on the problem computer? Does Safari work correctly in the new account?

Comment: @null On a new account, the website loads without issue. However I have now noticed that on my iMac at home - which synchronises Safari via iCloud - it does not work. So it looks like whatever is causing the breakage is included in synchronised data.

Comment: It seems iCloud [syncs HSTS entries](http://www.radicalresearch.co.uk/lab/hstssupercookies). So maybe turn off iCloud before deleting  `HSTS.plist` and then [restart your computer](http://sweetpproductions.com/support/showthread.php?tid=272)?

Answer (score 4):

Over at the [Apple Support Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5884595?start=15&tstart=0), the following was reported to resolve the issue:

1. Clear the cache
2. Delete all entries for the domain from the history
3. Delete HTST.plist
4. Reboot the system

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Since your site used to support HTTPS, you probably have a cached HSTS entry that directs Safari to always use HTTPS to connect to your site.

You can purge your HSTS settings in Safari like this:

- close Safari
- delete the **~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist** file on your disk (or edit the file and remove just your site entry if you want to preserve other entries)
- reopen Safari

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't made a difference. I tried both removing the individual entry with Xcode, and deleting the file entirely - no luck either time.

Comment: Are you sure your site isn't still sending the HSTS header? Can you actually show the full URL to the site, and/or post the complete response if you e.g. do 

    curl - D - -s -o /dev/null http://<your-site-here>.com/

Comment: If you want to test from within Safari, you can use Charles proxy to debug connection originating from it: http://www.charlesproxy.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clear the history in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

I know it seems silly have you tried the obvious?

- Go to Settings > Safari and Clear Cookies and Data
- Restart both your device and your router. When they boot again any old setting will get refreshed from the ISP, possibly fixing something.